# C#. Crop image on N rectangles

Tags: c#, image, crop

I need to crop image on N rectangles.

Condition for all rectangles:
Rectangle's width = X
Rectangle's height = X/2

Any algorithm ?

Comment: What do you mean? And is this homework?

Comment: no, I want to create a puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help you:

```
private static Image cropImage(Image img, Rectangle cropArea)
{
   Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
   Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea,
   bmpImage.PixelFormat);
   return (Image)(bmpCrop);
}
```

I found a more complex but complete example here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/e0c30a26-60da-457d-a217-ba95650deec8

Comment: I know how crop image on rectangle. But I dont know how crop image on N rectangles

Comment: the example in the link should be what you are looking for! Hope it helps